# Manipulate tag tree from tagged pdf

Tags: pdf, itext, accessibility, tagged-pdf

**Question:**
I was working on tags for accessibility with iText7 and I want to manipulate the structure of the tag tree.

**The task would be like.**
First of all, extract the tag tree from tree. Then, move the  node to it's parent node.

The demonstrate structure to be like this.

```
[Before]
<H1>
    <H2>
        <Span>
              "Description"
<H3>
    <Span>
          "Item"
```

```
[After]
<H1>
    <Span>
          "Description"
<H2>
    <Span>
          "Description"
<H3>
    <Span>
          "Item"
```

Is it possible to use some libraries to approach my goal?
As my understanding, the [tagUtils](https://github.com/itext/itext7/tree/62a6564b82da401353c017da47b3b01eff054f84/kernel/src/main/java/com/itextpdf/kernel/pdf/tagutils) in iText might be helpful.
I already trying parse tagged pdf with iText under pdf specification. Yet, it's extremely Unintuitive. Since the well-known pdf tools, Acrobat can show the tags on the panel to make the pdf be accessibility. It must be some libraries to extract the tag tree from tagged-pdf without pain.

[image]
[Imgur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iHRMW.jpg)

**Any response would be extremely helpful. Thanks.**